# WordPress send post URL to ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, wordpress

I'm using `wp_localize_script` to send post data to ajax.

```
wp_localize_script( 'my-script.js', 'ajax_object', array('ajax_url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php')) );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_load_more_posts', 'ajax_posts' );
```

Sending post data to ajax:

```
function ajax_posts(){
    global $post;
    $args = array('post_type'=>'post', 'posts_per_page'=> 2);
    $posts_arr=[];
    $query = new WP_Query($args);
    if($query->have_posts()):
        while($query->have_posts()):$query->the_post();

            $posts_arr[] = $post;

        endwhile;
        wp_reset_postdata();

    endif;
    wp_send_json_success(array('post'=>$posts_arr));
}
```

In my ajax success function I'm using the following to append posts to the HTML:

```
success:function(response){

     var post_data = response.data.post;

     $.each(post_data, function(index, value) {

        $("#content").append('<a href="How can I get the post URL here?">' + value.post_title + '</a>');

    });          

}
```

It adds 2 posts to the HTML. It works well but how can I also add the post url to the `ajax_posts()` php function and pass it to ajax and use?

This is the data I'm getting from ajax:

[image: Image link]

Is it possible to also add the post urls to the post arrays?

Note: I'm using ajax for loading more posts when clicking a button but simplified the code here. I cannot add php directly to the js. It must be sent from the `ajax_posts()` php function to ajax in my js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply do something like this:

```
function ajax_posts(){
    global $post;
    $args = array('post_type'=>'post', 'posts_per_page'=> 2);
    $posts_arr=[];
    $query = new WP_Query($args);
    if($query->have_posts()):
        while($query->have_posts()):$query->the_post();

            $posts_arr[] = array(
                'permalink' => get_permalink(),
                'ID' => $post->ID,
                'post_title' => $post->post_title,
                'post_content' => $post->post_content,
                'post_author' => $post->post_author,
                'post_date' => $post->post_date
                // Add more fields as needed here
            );

        endwhile;
        wp_reset_postdata();

    endif;
    wp_send_json_success(array('post'=>$posts_arr));
}
```